# Calling a Static Method, Getting error: LNK2019

Tags: c++, static

I'm having some troubles making a string utility class that has only static methods. Whenever I use a calling class to use a static method in my string utility class, it compiles with an LNK error, 2019. Any help would be much appreciated.
.h is below,

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static class StringUtil
{
public:
    static string Reverse(string);
   // bool Palindrome(string);
   // string PigLatin(string);
   // string ShortHand(string); 
private:
   // string CleanUp(string);
};
```

.cpp file is below,

```
   #include "StdAfx.h"
   #include "StringUtil.h"
   #include <iostream>

static string Reverse(string phrase)
{
    string nphrase = "";
    for(int i = phrase.length() - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        nphrase += phrase[i];
    }
    return nphrase;
}
```

and below is the calling class.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "StringUtil.h"

void main() 
{
    cout << "Reversed String: " << StringUtil::Reverse("I like computers!");
}
```

And when it runs, it shows

> Error 5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl StringUtil::Reverse(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?Reverse@StringUtil@@SA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V23@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl a10_StringUtil(void)" (?a10_StringUtil@@YAXXZ) H:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Object Oriented C++\Object Oriented C++\Object Oriented C++.obj  Object Oriented C++

and

> Error 6   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   H:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Object Oriented C++\Debug\Object Oriented C++.exe    1   1   Object Oriented C++

I feel like this is a very simple problem, but I'm used to programming in Java. I'm trying to teach myself how to code in c++ currently, hence my problem.

Comment: `static string Reverse(string phrase)` --> `static string StringUtil::Reverse(string phrase)`

Comment: *but I'm used to programming in Java* -- Don't use Java as a model in writing C++ code -- they are not the same language.  `static class StringUtil` -- There is no need for `static class`, just `class`.

Comment: That class is completely unnecessary in C++ – you can just use functions. Learn classless programming and liberate yourself.

Comment: Welcome. Please note that there's no need to include "solved" in the question title, as we can see (even elsewhere in the site) that you have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all in C++ we do not have **static classes**:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class StringUtil
{
public:
    static string Reverse(string);
   // bool Palindrome(string);
   // string PigLatin(string);
   // string ShortHand(string); 
private:
   // string CleanUp(string);
};
```

Second you forgot the **class name StringUtil** (owner):

```
string StringUtil::Reverse(string phrase)
{
    string nphrase = "";
    for(int i = phrase.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        nphrase += phrase[i];
    }
    return nphrase;
}
```

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static string Reverse(string phrase)
{
   ...
}
```

does not define the `static` member function of the class. It defines a file scoped non-member function. You need to use:

```
string StringUtil::Reverse(string phrase)
{
   ...
}
```